# CSS simple responsive design

Tags: css, html

im trying to build 3 divs. "left" "Center" and Right" all float to left. The "left" and "Right" div is fix in width (like side bars). The "center" div (content) is either auto or %.
When i re size my browser, In the case of (eg center  div 60%), the right div is pushed to a lower position. If i use (eg center div auto) I get "left" div in place, "center" div takes all remaining space and the "right" div below.

What I need is, "left" and "right" div fix dimension 250px. The "Center" one fills the remaining space between the "left and right" div. And on resize only the "center div" width changes to fit.

(Note: Of course im using media query) This stuff will be helpful to me from 750px to 950px.)

```
<style type="text/css">
#left {
float:left;
height: 200px;
width: 250px;
border: medium dashed #03F;
}

#center {
float:left;
height: 200px;
width: 60%;
border: medium solid #C00;
}

#right {
float:left;
height: 200px;
width: 250px;
border: medium dashed #0C6;
}
</style>


<div id="left">
</div>

<div id="center">
</div>

<div id="right">
</div>
```

Comment: Without using CSS3 media queries to adapt to each screen size you would be better off using a fluid layout. i.e percent based sizes for all columns otherwise on small devices your center column will be squashed.

Comment: Are you using media queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/87enE/

Create a `wrapper` and use `display:table;`. Then use `dislay: table-cell` for child elements:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

#left {
    display: table-cell;    
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
    border: medium dashed #03F;
}

#center {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 200px;
    border: medium solid #C00;
}

#right {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
    border: medium dashed #0C6;
}
```

For responsive concern, better use `percentage` instead of `fixed` width:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/87enE/3/

Comment: I can't see this working for a mobile device, the center column would be squashed.

Comment: @luke2012 I agree with you, but nonetheless this is what was asked for.

Comment: @tsterker It just seems so wrong, probably better off getting more information from the person than just providing them with a inadequate fix. When someone says responsive, I'm sure they want it to work on smaller devices, this will not.

Comment: @luke2012 My apologies, I missed the responsive title. I just read what he wrote about `fixed` left and right divs which really a contradict on the title.

Comment: @luke2012 the requirement has been said and i don't see anything wrong with what JunM got. i got almost exactly the same answer so i deleted mine.

Comment: @Craftein Until further clarification from the poster its contradictory. I don't think its clear enough to provide a sufficient answer.

Comment: @luke2012 Due to the fact that the OP didn't further specify any desired responsive behavior apart from the flexible center, it would be wrong to provide an answer that assumes arbitrary use cases. So the answer is quite precise in that sense. Even though I agree that it is good to point out the problems of this approach, I would argue that you can't even use a 3-column design on mobile devices effectively anyways.

Comment: @tsterker You are definitely right. I just got caught up with all the inherent problems a design like this could cause but there is no use speculating.

Comment: There's a point when every UI will break, so the OP should be using media queries to handle those breaks according by giving each break scenario its own stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

You should put all `div` under `table tr td` and give `first` and `last` td to **fix size** you want(in %) and `center` to 100%.

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#left {
float:left;
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
border: medium dashed #03F;
}

#center {
float:left;
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
border: medium solid #C00;
}

#right {
float:left;
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
border: medium dashed #0C6;
}
</style>


<table style="width:100%;">
<tr>
<td style="width:20%;">
<div id="left">
</div>
</td>
<td style="width:60%;">
<div id="center">
</div>
</td>
<td style="width:20%;">
<div id="right">
</div>
</td>
</table>
```

here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SGT23/1/)

**Note:** If you wish to keep it responsive, you need to give all width in `%` instead of `px`. Also you can get more details about about media queries [here](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/04/23/responsive-web-design-layouts-and-media-queries/)

It should help you!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In cases such as this, I believe FlexBox handles the situation the best. `#center`'s width will change to take up the remaining space.

```
<style>
#container {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
#left {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  order:0;
  border: medium dashed #03F;
}
#center {
  flex:1;
  order:1;
  height: 200px;
  border: medium solid #C00;
}
#right {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  order:2;
  border: medium dashed #0C6;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

[Fiddle Here:](http://jsfiddle.net/87enE/4/)

```
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">

    <div class="div" id="left">
    </div>
    <div class="div" id="center">
    </div>
    <div class="div" id="right">
    </div>

</div>
```

Good Luck..